# Calculated result in Firebird SELECT

Tags: sql, firebird, libreoffice-base

Can anyone explain why this works:

```
Select C1, C2, C1 + C2 as C3
from V1,V2
where C2 > 0
```

and

```
Select C1, C2, C1 + C2 as C3
from V1,V2
where C3 > 0
```

gives the following error:

```
*Dynamic SQL Error
*SQL error code = -206
*Column unknown
*C3
*At line 1, column 53
caused by
'isc_dsql_prepare'
```

This is using the Firebird version with LibreOffice 6.1.3

Comment: To which table(s) do the `C1`, `C2`, and `C3` columns belong?

Comment: Stop using SQL-89 implicit joins and start using SQL-92 explicit joins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use aliases from the `SELECT` column list in the `WHERE`-clause: you need to use the original column; the column list of a select is evaluated **after** the `where`. In other words, you'll need to use `where C1 + C2 > 0`

Alternatively, you need to use a sub-query:

```
select * 
from (Select C1, C2, C1 + C2 as C3 from V1,V2) a
where C3 > 0
```

And I strongly suggest that you start using SQL-92 explicit joins, as those are for more readable than SQL-89 implicit joins.